# how to solve "the following packages have unmet dependencies" error?

Tags: software-installation

when i am trying to install the software IRAF in 32 bit ubuntu 16.04, there is an error shown like " Unable to locate package libXmu6:i386 " how can solve this error.?

Comment: We need some more information here. How are you trying to install it? From what I can gather you just need to install libXmu6 as well.

Comment: i just tried to install it by using terminal.

Comment: Well yes, but how? What commands did you enter? Could you please edit your question and describe exactly what you did?

Comment: this is the command i entered  "sudo apt-get install tcsh libxss1 libncurses5 libXmu6:i386"

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, could you please accept it as well, so the question is marked as "solved"?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of installing it via `sudo apt-get install libXmu6:i386` you need to enter `sudo apt-get install libxmu6`.

Another tip: you can use [aptitude](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/aptitude.html) for things like this. Install aptitude via `sudo apt-get install aptitude` and then use aptitude to look up possible package matches using: `aptitude search libXmu6` and then install them via `sudo apt-get install <whatever_package_you_found>`